# what is the meaning of "Carfully curated" [By someone]

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "Carfully curated" [By someone] 
i couldn't find what it  means on online dectionaries , 
would you provide an explanation with examples ? 
thank you .

Comment: Do you understand the words 'carefully' and 'curated' on their own?

Comment: I think this is probably *carefully* rather than meaningless *carfully*. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carefully https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curate#Verb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure without the original text, but it's probably this meaning listed in the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curate):

```
Select, organize, and present (online content, merchandise, information, etc.), 
typically using professional or expert knowledge.
‘a curated alternative to the world's most popular video portal’
```